# basic_stringbuf has no member named 'freeze'

Tags: c++, c++11, ostringstream, strstream

The following code fails to compile:

```
#include <cstdio> 
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
   std::ostrstream strm;                         
   strm.rdbuf()->freeze(0);                      
}
```

I get the following errors on compilation:

```
g++ sample3.cpp
sample3.cpp: In function 'int main()':
sample3.cpp:5: error: 'ostrstream' is not a member of 'std'
sample3.cpp:5: error: expected `;' before 'strm'
sample3.cpp:6: error: 'strm' was not declared in this scope
```

After searching in google, I suspect that I should use ostringstream in place of ostrstream, so I have modified the program as below:

```
#include <cstdio> 
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
   std::ostringstream strm;                         
   strm.rdbuf()->freeze(0);                      
}
```

But now I get the following errors:

```
g++ sample3.cpp
sample3.cpp: In function 'int main()':
sample3.cpp:6: error: 'struct std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' has no member named 'freeze'
```

Comment: [freeze()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstreambuf/freeze) takes a bool or nothing, but not an int.

Comment: [`std::basic_stringbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf) doesn't have a member function named `freeze`, why do you think it should have? The [`strsteambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/strstreambuf) class is *deprecated*, and was from before C++ became standardized in 1998.

Comment: @Kevin I am passing 0 to freeze which should implicit type cast to bool ( " FALSE actually ).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg [rdbuf()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ostrstream/rdbuf) doesn't return a basic_stringbuf, but a strstreambuf*, which does have a method freeze()

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So what i should do in order to use freeze() function , when i declare std::ostrstream , then compiler gives error "'ostrstream' is not a member of 'std'"

Comment: You're thinking about the pre-standard `ostrstream` class, not the post-standard `ostringstream` which is a completely different thing. And the only thing you can do is to not use `freeze` since it's deprecated and can be removed anytime in the future. You better learn *modern* C++, even if it's the "old" C++03 variant.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : is there no equivalent to freeze function in modern c++?

Comment: There's no *need* for a call to the `freeze` member function if you start using an `ostringstream`. Unlike `strstreambuf`, you cannot ask a `basic_stringbuf` to stop managing itself. Figure out what exactly your original code was doing and then try to implement the same functionality using `stringstream` instead of trying to translate line by line,

Comment: @Praetorian : Thanks , I will try to understand my original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just scrap the `freeze()` call -- the current generation `std::ostringstream` doesn't expose its memory management guts to you like the old `ostrstream` did.  You'll need to rework your original code to let the stringstream manage memory in the way it wants (it'll be much simpler/less error-prone that way!).

Answer (score 0):

I should have changed `#include "sstream"` to `#include "strstream"`
then it will not report the error "*'ostrstream' is not a member of 'std'*".